# Efficient Way to Self Join on Table for Various Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

## Background

I'm working to find potentially duplicated payments / records in an AP system by self-joining on a table containing AP records. Generally, I have a pattern that works pretty well for decently large datasets. The issue arises when my matching criteria broadens and the number of matches per record gets too high (sometimes 20-100 matches per record). The resulting dataset can be massive and attempting to get `distinct` values takes too long.

## Current Solution

Query that runs fine when attempting to find matches on vendor, invoice number, date, and invoice amount:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DENSE_RANK()  OVER(ORDER BY ap.GtInvoiceNumber,     
ap.InvoiceDate, ap.InvoiceGrossAmount) PotentialDuplicate
,ap.Id EntryId
, ap.TransactionId
, ap.VendorNumber
, ap.InvoiceNumber
, ap.GtInvoiceNumber
, ap.InvoiceDate
, ap.PurchaseOrderNumber
, ap.InvoiceGrossAmount
, ap.InvoiceNetAmount
, ap.CheckNumber
, ap.CheckDate
FROM ApEntries ap 
INNER JOIN ApEntries sap ON 
ap.GtInvoiceNumber = sap.GtInvoiceNumber 
AND ap.InvoiceDate = sap.InvoiceDate 
AND sap.InvoiceGrossAmount = ap.InvoiceGrossAmount 
AND ap.VendorNumber =  sap.VendorNumber
AND ap.Id <> sap.Id 
WHERE ap.ClientId = @ClientId
```

This query runs in a matter of seconds because the number of rows that meet the criteria are very low and thus performing the `distinct` is simple.

Query that has issues when attempting to find matches on vendor, date, and invoice amount (excluding invoice number from the matching criteria):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DENSE_RANK()  OVER(ORDER BY ap.VendorNumber, ap.InvoiceDate, ap.InvoiceGrossAmount) PotentialDuplicate
,ap.Id EntryId
, ap.TransactionId
, ap.VendorNumber
, ap.InvoiceNumber
, ap.GtInvoiceNumber
, ap.InvoiceDate
, ap.PurchaseOrderNumber
, ap.InvoiceGrossAmount
, ap.InvoiceNetAmount
, ap.CheckNumber
, ap.CheckDate
FROM ApEntries ap 
INNER JOIN ApEntries sap ON 
ap.VendorNumber = sap.VendorNumber 
AND ap.InvoiceDate = sap.InvoiceDate 
AND ap.InvoiceGrossAmount =  sap.InvoiceGrossAmount
AND (ap.Id <> sap.Id AND ap.TransactionId <> sap.TransactionId)
WHERE ap.ClientId = @ClientId
```

This query takes on the order of 3-4 minutes to run because the criteria is too broad. Is there a better solution for this in SQL? I recognize that each match will be going both ways and I'll get a record back for each match, but also records for each match within the matched set, so a group of 5 will result in 30 rows, a group of 20 will result in 420 rows, and so on. How can I make this more efficient? I'd like to avoid using cursors, but I recognize that might be my only option.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

## Additional Info

Table is approximately 760k records (all of which are queried in these queried).

Query Stats for Bad Query
[image]

As you can see, I'm returning 13,824,170 rows from a table with 760k records. This due to the fact some groups are large (252 members for example will result in 63,756 records).

Relevant Indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ApEntries_DistinctIndex] ON [dbo].[ApEntries]
(
    [ClientId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Id],
    [VendorNumber],
    [InvoiceNumber],
    [GtInvoiceNumber],
    [InvoiceDate],
    [PurchaseOrderNumber],
    [InvoiceGrossAmount],
    [InvoiceNetAmount],
    [CheckDate],
    [CheckNumber],
    [TransactionId]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ApEntries_DupRep7] ON [dbo].[ApEntries]
(
    [VendorNumber] ASC,
    [InvoiceDate] ASC,
    [InvoiceGrossAmount] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ApEntries_Xid] ON [dbo].[ApEntries]
(
    [ClientId] ASC,
    [TransactionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Comment: Did you check index? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: I don't quite get why you need the self join. The window function would already show you which are duplicate?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify what I mean by "duplicate". I'm not looking for rows that are mathematically duplicated necessarily. I'm looking for rows, based on criteria defined by the business, that may indicate a transaction that was paid twice, so I join onto the table for those criteria to find rows that match those sets of criteria. If a match is found, that's potentially a duplicate record.

Comment: Maybe you can show us some sample data and expected result. That will give us a better idea of what your query does.

Comment: @michael I get that part but what I'm saying is can't you just find that with the window function? Isn't that essentially what you are already doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try with `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT ap.Id EntryId
             , ap.TransactionId
             , ap.VendorNumber
             , ap.InvoiceNumber
             , ap.GtInvoiceNumber
             , ap.InvoiceDate
             , ap.PurchaseOrderNumber
             , ap.InvoiceGrossAmount
             , ap.InvoiceNetAmount
             , ap.CheckNumber
             , ap.CheckDate
             , row_number() over 
               (partition by VendorNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceGrossAmount  
                order by TransactionId) rn
    WHERE ap.ClientId = @ClientId
   ) T
 WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: This got me to where I needed to be! Great solution. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I imagine you need something else to reach your goal, but is fast enough?

Comment: Oh yeah - down from 4 minutes and memory pressure to 6 seconds.